# Open a sub-cmd window with Python

Tags: python, sockets, cmd, subprocess

I'm making a cmd IRC client in Python. I want to receive data at the same time I can write message, in the previous code I did I could only write 2 messages and then it bugs and I can't write until it receives some kind of data.

The question is, can I have one cmd window running the received data and other one with a constant input waiting for me to write something to send?, maybe with threads?
I've looked through the subprocess library but I don't really know how to code it.

```
CMD1:
  while Connected:
     print socket.recv(1024)

CMD2:
  while Connected:
     text = raw_input("Text to send>> ")
     socket.send(text)
```

(This is a pseudocode not a real one)

Comment: You probably want to use *asynchronous* IO. There are lots of resources on the Internet for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach you are proposing could be done by making a server like application, and 2 client applications that connect via localhost to send and receive events. So that way you could have 2 terminals open , connected to the same session of the server.

On the other side you should consider a different design approach that include ncurses which allow you to make a terminal ui with input and output at the same terminal (two sections up and down). You can reference: http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/charming_python_6.html

Comment: Maybe including ncurses is the solution. I didn't know about that so I thought I couldn't do both things at the same time(input and output). Will check as correct if it all goes well